# Shiny app for creating bootstrapped normal distribution not refreshing each time with actionButton. How to refresh plot?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app demonstration of bootstrapping/Central Limit Theorem, and it generally works. However, I intended to have a Shiny app where each time "Simulate" is clicked, the plot refreshes and a new, different distribution is generated. However, each time I open the app and click "Simulate", the plot remains static and the same.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve/fix? It would be much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Define the user interface for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Add a title and sidebar
  titlePanel("Bootstrapped Distribution"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("num_sims", "Number of Simulations:",
                  min = 1, max = 10000, value = 100),
      sliderInput("sampleSize", "Sample Size:",
                  min = 1, max = 10000, value = 100),
    selectInput("distT", "Distribution Type:",
                c("Normal" = "norm",
                  "Exponential" = "exp",
                  "Gamma" = "gam",
                  "Poisson" = "pois",
                  "Binomial" = "binom")),
    actionButton("simulate", "Simulate")
    ),
    
    # Add a plot to the main panel
    mainPanel(plotOutput("dist_plot"))
  )
)

# Define the server logic for the app
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Create a reactive expression to simulate the bootstrapped distribution
  #dist_data <- reactive({
  dist_data <- reactive({

    if(input$distT == "norm"){
      bootstrapped_mean <- replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rnorm(input$sampleSize)))
    }else if(input$distT == "exp"){
      bootstrapped_mean <- replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rexp(input$sampleSize)))
    }else if(input$distT == "gam"){
      bootstrapped_mean <- replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rgamma(input$sampleSize, shape=1)))
    }else if(input$distT == "pois"){
      bootstrapped_mean <- replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rpois(input$sampleSize, lambda = 1)))
    }else if(input$distT == "binom"){
      bootstrapped_mean <- replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rbinom(input$sampleSize, size = 1, prob = .5)))
    }
    ggplot(data=tibble(mean=bootstrapped_mean), aes(x=mean)) +
      geom_histogram(bins=30) + jtools::theme_apa()
  })

  # Update the plot when the "Simulate" button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$simulate, {
    output$dist_plot <- renderPlot({
      dist_data()
    })
  }
  
  
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Break out `dist_data` to return *just* data, instead of trying to plot it as well. This app doesn't benefit a lot from this step, but it's a good way to organize what you're doing.

  For instance, if you later add a table that summarizes the random data, you don't have an easy way for the table to get the random data since `data_dist` was returning a ggplot grob, not the raw data.
- Add a dependency on `input$simulate` in your `dist_data` reactive block: this will cause the random data to be re-generated each time the button is pressed. **Without this**, the data will be generated once and never redone.
- Move `output$dist_plot` outside of the observer (which is no longer needed).

```r
library(shiny)
# library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Define the user interface for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Add a title and sidebar
  titlePanel("Bootstrapped Distribution"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("num_sims", "Number of Simulations:",
                  min = 1, max = 10000, value = 100),
      sliderInput("sampleSize", "Sample Size:",
                  min = 1, max = 10000, value = 100),
      selectInput("distT", "Distribution Type:",
                  c("Normal" = "norm",
                    "Exponential" = "exp",
                    "Gamma" = "gam",
                    "Poisson" = "pois",
                    "Binomial" = "binom")),
      actionButton("simulate", "Simulate")
    ),

    # Add a plot to the main panel
    mainPanel(plotOutput("dist_plot"))
  )
)

# Define the server logic for the app
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Create a reactive expression to simulate the bootstrapped distribution
  dist_data <- reactive({
    req(input$simulate)
    bootstrapped_mean <-
      if (input$distT == "norm") {
        replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rnorm(input$sampleSize)))
      } else if (input$distT == "exp") {
        replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rexp(input$sampleSize)))
      } else if (input$distT == "gam") {
        replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rgamma(input$sampleSize, shape = 1)))
      } else if (input$distT == "pois") {
        replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rpois(input$sampleSize, lambda = 1)))
      } else if (input$distT == "binom") {
        replicate(input$num_sims, mean(rbinom(input$sampleSize, size = 1, prob = 0.5)))
      }
  })

  output$dist_plot <- renderPlot({
    X <- req(dist_data())
    ggplot(data = tibble(mean = X), aes(x = mean)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
      jtools::theme_apa()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```